# RavenDB. Alternative to leading wildcard?

Tags: c#, lucene, ravendb

I have a RavenDB collection with approximately 1 million documents. One field in these documents is a string containing a domain name. I have a business requirement to let users search by a substring of the domain. For example a search for 'example' needs to return documents where the domain field contains example.com, example.net, or www.example.com.

Another standard search would be by domain extension such as .com which would return all .com domains.

It is not safe to assume that a period always delimits a search term.

I'm moving from a MS SQL environment and am trying to wrap my head around doing this without leading wildcard support. I realize Raven can use leading wildcards but such searches are expensive and slow. I've considered a reversed version of the field but that won't meet the requirement.

Is the NGram analyzer my answer? How can I meet my search requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to support arbitrary subsequences with tokens, yes, [ngram analyzer](http://www.nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Database.Analyzers/) is the right approach.

The example you've provided, though, should not require it.  Indexing "www.example.com" should produce a searchable token "example" (the standard Analyzer will, for instance), so no wildcards are necessary at all in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Store the string twice, one normal, once reversed.
Do StartsWith searches on both

Comment: I thought of that but in the case of www.example.com that won't help when the search string is example.